How to use setFreezeRow in spatie/simple-excel?
Does anybody know how to access OpenSpout\Writer\XLSX\Entity\SheetView from spatie/simple-excel? I would like to set `setFreezeRowv on the sheet.
Or is it possible to attach an OpenSpout\Writer\XLSX\Entity\SheetView instance to a Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelWriter object and go from there?
Or access the SheetView object from a Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelWriter $writer object?
Thanks a lot

Calling getWriter() on SimpleExcelWriter will give you the underlying OpenSpout\Writer\XLSX\Writer instance.

Wow! Thanks a lot. How could I miss that? Now I see it is mentioned in the Spatie package documentation at the very bottom.
So for reference - to freeze the top row:
$sheetView = new SheetView();
$sheetView->setFreezeRow(2);
$writer->getWriter()->getCurrentSheet()->setSheetView($sheetView);
with $writer being an instance of SimpleExcelWriter
